# Email HTML content with a text box and an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, email, gmail

I need to know if its possible to send email (in c#) with html content of a text box and `<a>` tag.

`<a>` tag will have a redirect address.

Clicking the `<a>` tag should take the data from text box and pass it as an argument.

The main problem is I am not able to get the value of the text box, because Java Script is not allowed in the mail content.

Anybody has any thoughts or views about this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, no.  But what sort of audience are you developing this for?  there could be a Google App Script or Add On if you're talking about gmail specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with form without using java script.

```
<form id='RejectFeedbackForm' method='get' action="http://localhost:49309/Controller/Action">
    Reason for rejection<br />
    <input type='text' name='comment' id='comment' /><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not be possible because an email cannot process user events. You can only reply to email, you need a landing page or something else that the user can interact on.